# How can I have a column with sum of smaller IDs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum

Assume I have a table like this:

```
id  pay
--  ---
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

I want to create a view from table above with this result:

```
id  pay  paid_before
--  ---  -------------
1   10   0
2   20   10
3   30   30
4   40   60
5   50   100
6   60   150
```

which "paid_before" is sum of pay rows that have smaller id.

How could I do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes what you want.

```
SELECT p1.id,p1.pay, sum(p2.pay) as Paid_Before FROM PAYMENTS P1 LEFT JOIN 
PAYMENTS P2 ON p1.id > p2.id
GROUP BY p1.id, p1.pay
```

See this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d05319/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this is most efficiently done with variables:

```
select p.id, p.pay, (@p := @p + p.pay) - p.pay as PaidBefore
from payments p cross join
     (select @p := 0) vars
order by id;
```

Although this is not standard SQL (which I usually prefer), that is okay.  The standard SQL solution is to use cumulative sum:

```
select p.id, p.pay, sum(p.pay) over (order by p.id) - p.pay as PaidBefore
from payments p;
```

Many databases support this syntax, but not MySQL.

The SQL Fiddle (courtesy of Atilla) is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d05319/6).

Comment: Thank you Gordon. but paid_before for the first record is 0. how can we modify this solution to have correct result?